# Suppress notification about one new video

Tags: youtube

Whenever I publish a new public video in my channel, then all the subscribers get a notification.

So far that's good, however, there is one video which I would prefer to "silently" put online.

So, is it possible to suppress such a notification for one single video ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On upload go to **advanced features** and **distribution options** uncheck the box that says notify subscribers.